# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

начинаю учить программировать, использовала субд sqlite, выдает ошибку, как можно решать, подскажите пожалуйста

```
def get_month_stats(user_id: int, year_month: str) -> str:
    cursor = db.get_cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT SUM(amount)"
        "FROM expenses "
        f"WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m', created) = '{year_month}' "
        f"AND user_id = {user_id}"
    )
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if not result[0]:
        stats += "В этом месяце ещё не было расходов."
        return stats
    all_month_expenses = result[0]
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT DISTINCT user_id "
        "FROM expenses "
        f"WHERE user_id = {user_id}"
    )
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return (f"Всего потрачено: {all_month_expenses}\n")
```

ошибка: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Comment: Кст, а откуда тут `stats` берется `stats += "В этом месяце ещё не было расходов."`? Если это глобальная переменная, то лучше ее явно передавать в функцию

Comment: Кст, а есть полный стек с ошибкой? Хотел убедиться, что именно в этой функции проблема

Answer (score 2):

Подстановка вручную значений в SQL плохая идея, лучше доверить это драйверу SQL:

```
def get_month_stats(user_id: int, year_month: str) -> str:
    cursor = db.get_cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT SUM(amount)"
        "FROM expenses "
        "WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m', created) = ? AND user_id = ?",
        (year_month, user_id)
    )
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if not result[0]:
        stats += "В этом месяце ещё не было расходов."
        return stats
    all_month_expenses = result[0]
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM expenses WHERE user_id = ?",
        (user_id,)
    )
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return f"Всего потрачено: {all_month_expenses}\n"
```

Comment: теперь пишет ошибку: in get_month_stats
    cursor.execute(
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @ruzakovvaa, что-то странное передаете. Что выводит `print(type(year_month), type(user_id))`?

Comment: @ruzakovvaa, в вашем отдельном вопросе по этой проблеме вам уже дали ответ - причина вы передавали неправильные данные, а именно в `user_id` передавали ссылку на встроенную функцию `id`, поэтому примите мой ответ, т.к. он решил проблему текущего вопроса :)